# how to change string matrix to a integer matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a voting dataset like that:

```
republican,n,y,n,y,y,y,n,n,n,y,?,y,y,y,n,y
republican,n,y,n,y,y,y,n,n,n,n,n,y,y,y,n,?
democrat,?,y,y,?,y,y,n,n,n,n,y,n,y,y,n,n
democrat,n,y,y,n,?,y,n,n,n,n,y,n,y,n,n,y
```

but they are both string so I want to change them to integer matrix and make statistic
hou_dat = pd.read_csv("house.data", header=None)

```
for i in range (0, hou_dat.shape[0]):
    for j in range (0, hou_dat.shape[1]):
        if hou_dat[i, j] == "republican":
            hou_dat[i, j] = 2
        if hou_dat[i, j] == "democrat":
            hou_dat[i, j] = 3
        if hou_dat[i, j] == "y":
            hou_dat[i, j] = 1
        if hou_dat[i, j] == "n":
            hou_dat[i, j] = 0
        if hou_dat[i, j] == "?":
            hou_dat[i, j] = -1

hou_sta = hou_dat.apply(pd.value_counts)
print(hou_sta)
```

however, it shows error, how to solve it?:

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError
(0, 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you need `map` and `stack`

```
map_dict = {'republican' : 2,
           'democrat' : 3,
           'y' : 1,
           'n' : 0,
           '?' : -1}

df1 = df.stack().map(map_dict).unstack()

print(df1)

   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16
0   2   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1  -1   1   1   1   0   1
1   2   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0  -1
2   3  -1   1   1  -1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0
3   3   0   1   1   0  -1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1
```

Comment: Thanks again, but where do I add path?

Comment: hou_dat = pd.read_clipboard("house.data",sep=" ", header=None) is not correct

Comment: @4daJKong you can ignore that, that was only to reproduce your data from above.

Comment: but my data from a dataset, name "house.data", how to import that?

Comment: hou_dat = pd.read_csv("house.data", header=None) you mean adding pd.read_clipboard directly? under this?

Comment: @4daJKong nope don't use that line at all, start at `map_dict`

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with data from csv, it is better to use pandas' methods.
In this case, you have `replace` method to do exactly what you asked for.

```py
hou_dat.replace(to_replace={'republican':2, 'democrat':3, 'y':1, 'n':0, '?':-1}, inplace=True)
```

You can read more about it in this [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)